# Interpretation of wavefunction in the Feynman formulation of QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, propagator

Feynman had this alternative way of doing QFT in which particle states are evolved forward in proper time. Specifically, the propagator is given by :

$$U(x_1,t_1,x_2,t_2)=\int _0^{\infty} d\tau \langle x_1,t_1| e^{-iH\tau}|x_2,t_2\rangle$$

where $H$ is $\partial _{\mu} \partial ^{\mu}+m^2-i\epsilon$. But, how do probabilities enter in this formulation of QFT? This propagator describes non-unitary evolution (because of the integration over $\tau$), so I don't think we can think about this in terms of the evolution of a probabilistic wavefunction. So, what exactly is the propagator propagating in this formulation, if it's not a probabilistic wavefunction?

This propagator is also equal to the path integral of the relativistic free particle action. My problem is that, without any probabilistic interpretation, this propagator just gives physically meaningless complex numbers. If it's non-unitary, how can there be a probabilistic interpretation?

**Can this propagator be used to evolve a wavefunction like in non relativistic QM and make probabilistic predictions?**

Comment: Which reference? Which page? Which eq.?

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanu Padmanabhan's QFT. page 24

Comment: @Qmechanic Equation 1.94

Comment: @Qmechanic I haven't lifted the entire question from the book though. I researched about this. This is called the worldline formulation of QFT. My problem is, how does this formulation make probabilistic predictions?

Comment: Propagator is the retarded Green's function of the Schrödinger equation (up to a coefficient).

Comment: @RogerVadim But this propagator is not unitary